# Show string in fixed size TextView

Tags: android, textview

i have TextView with fix width and height and want to set String `"._MealTracker_2-MAR-2012_02-20PM.apk"` but in textview only display `"."` could not get it. why its happen ?

```
      <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TextView01"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/bottom_margin"
                    android:text="._MealTracker_2-MAR-2012_02-20PM.apk"
                    android:textColor="@color/bgblue" />
```

Comment: Have you tried setText() ? or setting the width to "wrap_content" ?

Comment: yes i have setText in my code

Comment: Have you tried setText("._MealTracker_2-MAR-2012_02-20PM.apk") ?

Comment: do you want that height and width fix ?

Comment: yes i want that view height and width fix

Comment: do you want to show fullname with width=60dp ?

Comment: no full name is not an issue but at least according to width name should display

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set Your text property

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

Answer (score 2):

It not show properly because android:singleLine property is not set so it consider multiline . Because of that your text set as vertical.

If you set `android:singleLine="true"` then **._MealT...** is display in textView.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I try to write your string in a my textView and it works for me..
so perhaps it is a problem of spacing of the textView  because your string is to long to be print in a single line.